# Track down the cause of Windows Error Reporting Service starting

Tags: windows-7, crash, windows-error-reporting

Is it possible to find out the crashing process that causes the following event log message:

> 7/05/2013 2:58:00 PM - The Windows Error Reporting Service service entered the running state.

Immediately after it there "multimedia class scheduler" restarts, but can I be sure that it was the process that crashed?

> 7/05/2013 2:58:55 PM - The Multimedia Class Scheduler service entered the running state.

Here is the raw event data for the crash message:

```
System 
  - Provider 
  [ Name]  Service Control Manager 
  [ Guid]  {555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-26931d2012f4} 
  [ EventSourceName]  Service Control Manager      
- EventID 7036 
[ Qualifiers]  16384  
Version 0  
Level 4  
Task 0  
Opcode 0  
Keywords 0x8080000000000000  
- TimeCreated 
  [ SystemTime]  2013-05-07T04:58:00.199140400Z  
EventRecordID 41494  
Correlation  
- Execution 
  [ ProcessID]  740 
  [ ThreadID]  7852  
Channel System  
Computer Luke-PC  
Security 
- EventData 
  param1 Windows Error Reporting Service 
  param2 running 
  5700650072005300760063002F0034000000 
--------------------------------------------
Binary data:
0000: 57 00 65 00 72 00 53 00   W.e.r.S.
0008: 76 00 63 00 2F 00 34 00   v.c./.4.
0010: 00 00                     ..
```

I've looked at my process list and there's not process with PID 740. Services.exe is 736 and lsass.exe is 764.

Thanks!